# Insert values from fixed cells onto new line and calculate again

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to creating Macro's so I could use some help.
I have two tables, each calculating a certain value in one specific cell by making use of following macro:

```
Macro12 Macro
' CALCULATE
    Range("H16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-5]C:R[-1]C)"
    Range("H26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-5]C:R[-1]C)"
    Range("H27").Select
End Sub
```

Now I want the value of cell H16 in cell K10, and cell H26 in cell L10, by pressing my ADD button.

If I make the calculation again, new values will appear. These ones need to be added, by pressing that same ADD button, in cell K11 and L11. (So the old ones needs to be stored.)

I'd be grateful if you can help.

**Added from comment**

I did some work on it though:

```
  Range("H16").Select
  Selection.Copy Range("K10").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Range("H26").Select Selection.Copy
  Range("L10").Select Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Look at the Help Centre (button in top line) for guidance on asking questions appropriate for this site.  Asking for a macro that calculates two values and places them in the first and second columns of a table is a bad question because you have not demonstrated effort and it is too vague.

Comment: I did some work on it though;
 Range("H16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("H26").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub

Comment: I have copied your comment to the question so it was readable.  I agree with Ripster suggestions for removing `Select`s.  The only thing I would add it that H16 will be recalculated if the source range changes but K10 will not because you are copying the current value.  You could try `Range("K10").Value = "=H16"` if you want K10 to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value of a cell using `Range().Value = SomeValue`

For example if you have a formula in Cell H16:
`Range("H16").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-5]C:R[-1]C)"`

and you want its value to show up in K10 you can do this:
`Range("K10").Value = Range("H16").Value`

Comment: I sincerely thank you for this help!

Is there anyway I can make my macro insert these values in the next row, the second time I press the ADD button? For instance by adding conditions?

Comment: I don't know what the layout of your workbook is so it is kind of hard to help. If you post another question with more information about your excel sheet I can probably help.